# What to do when MySQL query returns empty set?

Tags: php, mysql

I just started learning PHP and MySQL. I'm now doing a miniproject for course enrollment.
I use table `coursetbl` to store course info like code, name, quota.
When a user fills out application form, I'd first check if he/she filled in a valid course code, by

`$coursevalid=mysql_query("select * from coursetbl where courseno = '$_POST[courseno]'");
$cvalid = mysql_num_rows($coursevalid);
if ($cvalid=1) {echo "Course number validated.<br />";}
else {die( "Invalid course code.");}`

When the input code is valid, all is well. But when it's not, `$coursevalid` stores an 'empty set', which got me curious. What's the data type of an empty set? Can it be used in a logic clause, like 
`if($coursevalid = '') {...}`?
I googled mysql empty set but didn't spot a satisfactory explanation. Hope someone can explain in some detail how does this thing works. THX.

Comment: `if(!$coursevalid)`,`if(empty($coursevalid))`, or `if(is_null($coursevalid))` would all work because  empty arrays(such as result sets) evaluates to false in php

Answer (score 1):

`mysql_query()` returns a resource which you can then use to return various pieces of information, including any data your query might have found. You can't compare the value of a resource with anything - it's just an internal identifier used by the PHP functions. There's no concept of an 'empty set' in this context.

You can check this in a couple of ways. You're already looking at `mysql_num_rows()` to check for the number of returned items. You can check for an 'empty set' by looking there for zero.

Alternatively, you can simply retrieve rows from the set with `mysql_fetch_array()` or similar until the function return `false`, at which point there are no more rows to retrieve.

**Note:** the `mysql_*()` functions are deprecated. You shouldn't use them for new code. Use `mysqli_*()` or `PDO` instead.

**Note also**, you're not escaping the `$_POST['courseno']` variable. This is a prime target for SQL injection. At the very least you should use `mysql_real_escape_string()` on it before submitting your query, but you should really look at using prepared statements.